# Problem!You must specify a source image in your preferences

Tags: codeigniter

Hi everybody i`m trying to upload an image with codeigniter  on my localhost(WAMP) but two problems appeared:

You must specify a source image in your preferences.

Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.

I tried what not to fix it but no result

Here it is my code :

```
class Upload_mod extends CI_Model{

  var $gallery_path;
  var $gallery_path_url;

  function index(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../uploads');
    $this->gallery_path_url = base_url().'uploads/';
  }

  function do_upload() {
    $config = array(
      'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
      'upload_path'   => $this->gallery_path);

    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();
    $image_data = $this->upload->data();
    print_r($image_data);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
      $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
      gd_info();
      echo $error;
    }    

    $config['source_image'] = $image_data['full_path'];
    $config['new_image'] = $this->gallery_path . '/thumbs';
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = 75;
    $config['height'] = 50;

    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();

    if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
    {
      echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing here, but I think the problem is that you're calling `$this->image_lib->resize()` twice, but the second one's configuration is cleared after you run the first one - so it's not finding the file, and that's triggering the second error. "this type of image" is probably a NULL value or something. You're doing error checking only on the second call as well, so the first one may very well be working fine.

Try this change and see if it helps:

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
// $this->image_lib->resize(); Remove this call to resize()

if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
{
  echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}
```

Another way you can do it:

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$success = $this->image_lib->resize();

if ( ! $success)
{
  echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}
```

Either way, and even if this is not your only issue, you should only call `resize()` once.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no change .

Comment: What does `var_dump($image_data['full_path'])` return? If it seems to a proper path, try wrapping `is_file()` around it and see what happens. If you get any interesting results, add them to your question.

Answer (score 0):

In php.ini
you have to change this line 
upload_max_filesize = 2MB